# Starting a task in hazelcast lasts > 2 sec sometimes

Tags: java, execution, hazelcast

we are using Hazelcast distributed tasks a lot and realized, that sometimes just starting a task lasts > 2 sec, even before the task itself is executed. We did this on a single machine; that is, no network overhead. The task executed itself has just a single line of code in its call() method (we placed a System.currentTimeMillis() at beginning and end) stores the passed argument "client" in its constructor call - nothing else.

Task is started as follows:

```
FutureTask<Member> task = new DistributedTask<Member>(new NotifyWaitingClientTask(client),
            theId);
    ExecutorService executorService = hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService();
    executorService.execute(task);
...
task.get();
```

Question is: is this a usual time? We expected rather milliseconds on local machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal unless you have two many tasks that take too much time and the Executor threads are already occupied. So the task will not start until there is an available thread to execute and you'll see that latency.

If this is not the case, can you come up with the code that we can run and reproduce the issue.

Fuad

Hazelcast

Comment: Increasing these thread sizes in hazelcast.xml helped a lot! Thanks!